# kafka rest proxy API specify the numbers of records you want to get

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

[kafka rest proxy](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka-rest/api.html#get--consumers-(string-group_name)-instances-(string-instance)-records) specify the numbers of records you want to get.

> GET /consumers/(string:group_name)/instances/(string:instance)/records
>
> Fetch data for the topics or partitions specified using one of the subscribe/assign APIs.

This api is used to fetch records from topic. Is there a convenient paramter to get specify the numbers of records I want to get.

For example, I want to get 10 records from a certain offset.
This api only have two query parameters, **timeout** and **max_bytes**.
There is no parameter like **limit_num**.

> POST /consumers/(string:group_name)/instances/(string:instance)/positions
>
> Overrides the fetch offsets that the consumer will use for the next set of records to fetch.

I can use this api to set up the starting offset I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.

You'd have to consume more than needed, then commit back a lower offset value than the number of records you did consume